Why C is fine with overwriting memory sometimes? Fatal glibc error: malloc assertion failure in sysmalloc
Why code A works fine, but code B gives an error?
The only difference is a printf. Also note that I'm accessing out of range memory.
And GCC is fine with that. I even overwritten RAM memory easily in example A.
Compiler error:
Fatal glibc error: malloc assertion failure in sysmalloc: (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)

My code peace:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
#if 1
    // A
    int *items = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    printf("allocated: %lu bytes\n", 10 * sizeof(int));
    items = items;
    items[0] = 5;
    items[9] = 5;
    items[10] = 5;
    printf("[");
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", items[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
#else
    // B
    int *items = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    items = items;
    items[0] = 5;
    items[9] = 5;
    items[10] = 5;
    printf("[");
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", items[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}


I tried to ask chatgpt why it works, it says it's because my RAM is not enough, which is nosense.
I would expect segfaults in both examples.

Writing out-of-bounds of your allocation causes undefined behavior. Should be explained on the first pages of any introduction to using dynamic memory in C. The compiler is in no way required to make sure that your program behaves in any sensible way. What do you expect instead and why?

"I tried to ask chatgpt why it works, it says it's because my RAM is not enough, which is nosense.": Yes, and good that you noticed it here. The problem with ChatGPT is that it may also give you a more convincing-looking answer that still is non-sense and then, especially someone who is not already an expert on the matter, may believe it. So don't use ChatGPT for anything more than getting directions for research into more trustworthy sources.

Btw. what do you think items = items; is going to achieve? Also, the format specifier  %lu is wrong. The format specifier for sizte_t (the type of sizeof(/*...*/) is %zu).

ok got it, i would expect segmentation fault I think in both examples.

this code is ripped out of context, I forgot to remove those lines.

@user17732522 Shh - don't tell anyone that! Its part of natural selection, that now some greedy managers fire half their team, believing the AI hype ;)

idk it just works with lu, but thanks i will use zu!

A segmentation fault happens only if the virtual address that you are trying to access is not mapped for your process (or mapped with incorrect permissions). A page is typically 4kB long and your malloc allocation lies somewhere in it. There may also be further pages mapped after it. As long as you do not cross outside the mapped pages, you don't get a segmentation fault. What pages are mapped depends on what malloc decides to do. There are no guarantees one way or another. If the pages are mapped but outside your allocation, then you simply overwrite whatever else happens to be there.

This question is similar to: How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


I would expect segfaults in both examples.

Nothing in the C standard says that a C implementation should give you a memory access violation when you overrun allocated memory. Nor does any proper tutorial or textbook. Some learning material may have mentioned that a segmentation fault may happen, but it is not a certainty.
Generally, it is impossible to guarantee a memory access violation because hardware typically handles memory in blocks called pages, commonly 4096 or 8192 bytes, but malloc allocates memory in smaller units, often blocks of 16 bytes.  (Even if you request a smaller amount or an amount that is not a multiple of 16 bytes, malloc may still do its work in units of 16-byte blocks.) So, if you allocate 40 bytes for ten int, there is no way to mark the memory immediately after those 40 bytes as inaccessible. The hardware provides a 4096-byte page, and it has no way to say that 40 of those bytes can be accessed and the rest cannot.
The standard C memory management routines are not specified to prevent incorrect access. C generally is not designed to prevent your program from doing improper things. It is to help you write low-overhead programs. As part of that, it avoids the overhead of checking everything your program does. It is your job as a programmer to ensure your program is correct.
As for the difference between your two code sequences, one of them, in overrunning the array, happened to alter data that the memory management routines use for their record keeping. When they detected this, they reported an error. The difference is likely that things happened to be arranged in memory differently between the two code sequences.

"there is no way to mark the memory immediately after those 40 bytes as inaccessible." -- there sure is (Electric Fence). Just no practical way to do so.
